# Missing district data with v7 API

Tags: here-api

I've noticed that "district" data is not returned with the v7 api. At least not with the `revgeocode` and `lookup` endpoints that I've tried. How can I get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiving the "district" of a point depends on how administrative divisions work in that place. If the country uses "district" as an administrative division, you will get it in the response. E.g.

```
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?apikey={{apiKey}}&at=52.5,13.4
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Neuenburger Straße 21, 10969 Berlin, Deutschland",
            "id": "here:af:streetsection:2wUtzSvdGL0dYtTkTD2UxB:CgcIBCCirOZQEAEaAjIx",
            "resultType": "houseNumber",
            "houseNumberType": "PA",
            "address": {
                "label": "Neuenburger Straße 21, 10969 Berlin, Deutschland",
                "countryCode": "DEU",
                "countryName": "Deutschland",
                "stateCode": "BE",
                "state": "Berlin",
                "countyCode": "B",
                "county": "Berlin",
                "city": "Berlin",
                "district": "Kreuzberg",
                "street": "Neuenburger Straße",
                "postalCode": "10969",
                "houseNumber": "21"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 52.49991,
                "lng": 13.39976
            },
            "access": [
                {
                    "lat": 52.50002,
                    "lng": 13.39988
                }
            ],
            "distance": 19,
            "mapView": {
                "west": 13.39545,
                "south": 52.49947,
                "east": 13.40042,
                "north": 52.5007
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In places where county/ commune is the administrative division, the county name is returned in the district object

```
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?apikey={{apiKey}}&at=-32.86558,-71.23689
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Sport Club",
            "id": "here:pds:place:15266jm4-24c37d92509f4f1aa61a79c1c7979731",
            "resultType": "place",
            "address": {
                "label": "Sport Club, Calle Los Queltehues, 2260000 Quillota, Valparaíso, Chile",
                "countryCode": "CHL",
                "countryName": "Chile",
                "stateCode": "VS",
                "state": "Valparaíso",
                "county": "Quillota",
                "city": "Quillota",
                "district": "Quillota",
                "street": "Calle Los Queltehues",
                "postalCode": "2260000"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": -32.86571,
                "lng": -71.23687
            },
            "access": [
                {
                    "lat": -32.86571,
                    "lng": -71.23687
                }
            ],
            "distance": 15,
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "100-1000-0000",
                    "name": "Restaurante",
                    "primary": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful information. Is this in the docs somewhere?